# Do the editing penalty durations increase?

Tags: support, edit-ban

I got a temporary ban for editing (1 day).

If I got another one, would it be for more days?

Comment: Your history of edit suggestions is at https://stackoverflow.com/users/8160917/krum?tab=activity&sort=suggestions. For example, looking at [your last one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17126499) you suggested to change _will be shown_ to _will be show_, which is, I believe, wrong in English.

Comment: @Cœur You're correct. Krum's edit introduced one error. 1st rejected edit: "I am" is more formal than "I'm", but both are correct. "Shown" was correct, "Show" was definitely incorrect. However he was correct to remove the space before "with". 2nd rejected edit: Wow this post is a complete train wreck and should be rewritten entirely, I'd tackle this one but it would probably get rejected as "deviates too far from original intent" (darn!). Anyway, thanks Krum for trying to clean up the site, but you may want to avoid doing grammar edits, you should probably leave that to somebody else for now.

Comment: @jrh - Both are correct but it is *not* correct to change clear and correct text for style reasons and call it a grammar correction. Looking at their other edits, the OP has a bad habit of making this particular change. Some of their edits do nothing but change "I am" to "I'm".

Comment: @BSMP Even as somebody who supports minor (even single character) edits, I agree about "I am" to "I'm", there's no improvement there. Hypothetically if I reviewed edits (I don't have the rep, and probably never will) I would accept "I'm" -> "I am" because arguably SO should use the formal form because it's trying to make a reference site (even though that level of strict formal writing isn't really common anymore outside of academia). Though, if I saw a bunch of these I'd start to wonder if the editor was a frustrated Harvard writing professor or something.

Comment: Disclaimer: Note that me hypothetically accepting "I'm" -> "I am" is not a recommendation, I am not an edit reviewer and if you are suggesting edits I strongly suggest NOT doing edits like that, because it's very likely to be rejected as "no improvement whatsoever". The previous comment does not reflect the current policies in place on SO.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Edit bans come in 3 forms:

1. When you have enough edits rejected in a short period of time, you will receive an automatic suggested edit ban that lasts 7 days.  This ban is not shorter or longer.  So if you've been banned for a period more or less than 7 days, you likely did not get an automatic ban, and instead were banned manually by a moderator
2. Manual edit bans can be levied by moderators for any infraction that they feel warrants a ban (such as editing spam into posts).
3. IP level bans used to rate limit anonymous suggested edits.  More explanation on it is in [How can an anonymous user get an edit ban if all their edits were approved?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387506/how-can-an-anonymous-user-get-an-edit-ban-if-all-their-edits-were-approved/387509#387509)

The first type does not have any kind of progressive growth.  It is a 7 day ban regardless of how long and how many times you've been banned in the past.  The 2nd type is completely up to the discretion of the moderator.  If they feel you should be banned for a longer period of time, that is completely their prerogative.  In this case, previous edit bans or a history of poor editing may result in a longer edit ban. You can, of course, appeal such actions by asking on meta or emailing the Stack Overflow community team.

But since these are timed bans, they are not intended to be punitive.  They are merely to slow you down and let you reflect on what you may have been doing wrong, and learn from it, so you can become a positive contributor to the community in the future.

Comment: I wonder how many rejected edits can lead to a ban. I got two rejected as the proposed edit was minor correction. Not consecutive though.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I am not sure if the algorithm has changed, but the one i remember was `(rejects - (approvals / 3)) >= 5`.  So it isn't a fixed number and is based heavily on your success rate.  Source: [Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days
](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days/92337#92337)

Comment: It's also a 7-day ban if your IP is banned for suggesting an anonymous edit that trips the additional content filter that anonymous users' edits are put through.

Comment: @gparyani do you have a link for the source on that?  Feel free to edit that in to the answer if you can find one

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. I don't think there is a published source for it; I only remember from the time I used to do anonymous edits over on Meta.SE. (Also, I don't have enough rep to edit.)