# How long am I banned from editing?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, suggested-edits, edit-ban

Recently I have been doing a lot of edits that remove the [design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design) tag, as it is being burninated. See: [The [design] tag is being burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320690/the-design-tag-is-being-burninated).

So recently I have suggested quite a few edits, by only removing the design tag. A lot of them were rejected and now I understand that I need to edit the question as well as removing the design tag, by reading this: [How do tag removal (burnination) requests work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work)

Now when I try to edit I get this:

[image: Banned from suggesting edits]

When I suggested those edits I thought I could only just remove the tag, but after doing research I was wrong.

So now I want to know how long will I be banned for?

Comment: *Your edit should improve all problems with the question and remove the design tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".* I think we should add: *and is best left to users with full edit privileges (aka > 2K reputation)*

Comment: Yes I understand that now, I just want to know how long am I blocked for?

Comment: That ban is handed out by a mod so they have to chime in.

Comment: Is there any way I can find out how long the ban is?

Comment: No, you can't but I pinged some moderators to make them aware of this post. They are timezone challenged so give it 6 to 8 hours for a response.

Comment: Looks like it's an automated one the system issues when N many suggested edits are rejected in N period of time - the ban expires in 7 days.

Comment: Since though, you were doing so in good faith and understand that you should be doing more with suggested edits than just tag removal, and that a suggested edit ban is only really there to stop you potentially doing more harm than good, I've lifted it... you're free to make suggested edits again... just make them more substantial than tag only edits please.

Comment: @JonClements No problem, so if I edit and improve the post and remove the tag it will be fine?

Comment: Yes... reviewers should approve such things. It might be easier if you take the approach of not coming at it from a "I'm doing this to remove the tag and should find something else to edit so it gets approved" but more a "when I'm looking at a post with the design tag - is there a decent amount of work I can do to improve the post itself and it just so happens I can remove the design tag as part of it"

Comment: No one has mentioned it, and maybe you were already doing it, but when you remove the tag (and do anything else) be sure to mention in a comment WHY (point to the burninate discussion) so that reviewers of the edit queue understand what's going on when they encounter a slew of "the same edit".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355727), if the ban was caused by having too many suggested edits rejected, the length is fixed at 7 days.

If unfortunately a moderator spotted your behaviour and manually issued this ban, then no one knows how long it is - you have to consult the moderator team so they can have a look. But common sense prevails, so if this is your first offense, it's unlikely a moderator will ban you for long.

As a bottom line, try to learn how Stack Overflow works before putting into practice. Batch suggesting edits to remove a tag that's pending burnination is not that helpful. Try to focus on more severe issues like wrongly formatted code, blatant mistakes, etc. when suggesting edits.

Comment: Yet another edit to that... The original version was correct; "is your having" is making the gerund "having" possessed by the OP.  However, "is you're having = is you are having" doesn't completely make sense without another word added, like "is *that* you're having," or punctuation, like "is:  you're having..." This new edit, "was caused by having," is correct, but it seems silly to edit it into something new when the original was completely correct to begin with.

Answer (score 18):

We now have much clearer messaging on-screen for users when they have suggested edit ban. It looks like this:

[image: Message on new post notice: "You are currently suspended from suggesting edits. You will be able to suggest edits again in time-to-end-of-suspension. In the meantime, read about how suggested edits are reviewed and visit your edit history."]

The message itself (now in a nicer post notice element) says:

> You are currently suspended from suggesting edits. You will be able to suggest edits again in time-to-end-of-suspension. In the meantime, read about how suggested edits are reviewed and visit your edit history.

The message will link to the review/suggested edits [help center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-suggested-edits) as well as the [user’s edit history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=activity&sort=revisions).