# How long am I banned from suggesting edits?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, edit-ban

I got this message from the moderators:

[image: Moderator's Message]

And when I wanted to suggest another edit, I got this message:

[image: Ban Message]

And when I clicked the "your edit history", I went here:

[image: Edit History]

But how long am I banned to suggest edits?

Comment: interesting. When I was banned from editing it was easy to discover for how long. But that was about 10 years ago and I can't remember where exactly I found that info, wonder if things have changed since (as a side note, your browser indicates that it needs to be updated)

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/is-there-a-penalty-for-ones-edit-suggestion-being-rejected/78192#78192) suggests 7 days but it's talking about automatic bans rather than moderator imposed bans.

Comment: According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376094/how-long-am-i-banned-from-editing), there is no way to know without asking a moderator.  Which...really seems like a problem worth fixing: people should be able to know how long they're suspended.

Comment: That said, there's a very good chance it's 7 days, because I think moderators tend to pick the default unless there's a good reason not to, and I don't really see one here.  But that's pure speculation.

Answer (score 14):

It's 7 days. I'm not sure why the interface doesn't tell you that.

I'm going to ping a dev to see if they overlooked something. The [new review suspension notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351118/improved-experience-for-users-with-review-suspensions) went live today so that might have something to do with it.

Comment: [already pinged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303584/new-review-navigation-does-not-tell-review-banned-users-what-happened-or-why/351228#comment1176260_351228)

Comment: The review suspensions are separated from the suggested edits ban ;) This question may become the basis for a FR.

Comment: Yeah, talked with some other mods and apparently there's no native notice for it, and there never has been. That particular mod communication is wholly a free form entry