# How can an anonymous user get an edit ban if all their edits were approved?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, anonymous-user

I’ve not been using my account at work, so all my edits there are anonymous suggested edits. I know how to make good edits and in fact my [most recent one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23594720) says:

> *Anonymous* had 10 edit suggestions approved, and 0 edit suggestions rejected

After making that edit (and probably before it got approved), I was editing a link-only answer to change the link and add a quote, and when I tried to submit the edit I was banned, losing all the content of the edit. (“You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits - please review your edit history.”) Unfortunately due to the bug reported in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293022/323179) the link to my “edit history” redirects me to [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com), which obviously doesn’t help me figure out how I got banned or what to do about it.

Furthermore my approved edit linked above has a spam warning (“Our system has identified this edit as possible spam; please review carefully”.) I’m not sure if this is related to me being edit banned, but I would also like to know why I got that message too.

Did I get [instantly banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/323179)? Or is it the fault of someone else on my network? I can’t even say if I changed IPs or not.

(Update: On July 30th, my work IP  was unbanned. But I just ran into the ban again today.)

Also shouldn’t anonymous users with a good track record be given a clearer explanation than this? If I can’t figure this out as an experienced user, no doubt most people will be completely baffled.

Comment: Not an A to your Q, but making anonymous edits that require others to review,  when you have edit rights, adds unnecessary workload to the community.  Can't you just wait 'till you get to location where you _are_ willing to log in before editing g?

Answer (score 26):

We have had problems in the past with very major anonymous edit suggestions being spam. Enough so that we prevent them and temporarily hobble the IP address the edit came from to prevent more of it.

You hit the "Special note for anonymous edits" section from the MSE FAQ you linked to.

> Because a large proportion of anonymous edits are spam or abusive, anonymous edits are heavily rate-limited and there is an extra filter that checks all anonymous edits. If your edit trips the filter, it will be silently disregarded and you will be instantly banned from suggesting edits temporarily.

You have a couple of solutions... you can log in to edit posts, which would avoid the need to suggest edits at all. That said, I know that some people prefer to avoid using their accounts in some situations, so, if that's the case, the alternative is to not change every line in a post. As it was explained to me "the % calc is... kinda dumb".

The spam warning on the one you link to was added because the subsequent edit was marked as spam (though incorrectly). The idea being that if one of your edits was considered spam by the system, others may also be spam.

You won't be banned tomorrow because I've unhobbled the IP address.

Comment: So, suggested edits made anonymously should avoid changing more than 50% (or some similar undisclosed percentage) of the lines of the post?

Comment: By the way, my work IP is still edit banned. Is there any way you can look into unbanning it again or tell me when the ban expires? I don’t want the IP to be banned because of me

Comment: @Laurel We're checking. Thanks for letting me know and sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: I can’t seem to stop myself from getting banned, although I think I’m on a slightly different IP now.

Comment: This is annoying. As a >2k user I wanted to make a major edit that I was unsure about, so I suggested it as an anonymous user so that others can have a look at before it's applied.  But because of this, my edit (that I spent some time on) got instantly dismissed without anyone having looked at it and without there even being any way to recover it.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I think you can still find the edit in the timeline of the post.

Comment: @Scratte No, I can't. I checked the timeline, and there's no trace of it.