# How can we report anonymous user edits?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, questions

I just recently realized anonymous users can submit a suggested edit for posts on SO. I found out because someone tried to edit one of my posts and was clearly being a troll.

[image]

It is my understanding moderators can see the IP and probably put a block on them for a bit, but there does not appear to be any report option in the suggested edit window.

If a post has been rejected due to **"This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive."** Then is that poster ever reviewed by moderators or any way of preventing this kind of action going forward?

Maybe a report post button here would be good or, if it doesn't already exist, a flag that is automatic for moderator review when something is rejected for this reason?

I know there are rejection categories that fit. I am asking what can be or is being done about a post like this. Is it just "reject and forget" or is there something more that is preventing these kind of people from constantly trying stuff like this?

Comment: Well, I'd suspect these won't survive the edit review queue for long, no? Doen't matter if 5 mentally sane users or a mod rejects this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes I agree but what action can be taken proactively to prevent this user from doing more. Maybe more subtle edits that are not obviously bad. IP banning. Though now that I think about it VPN's come to mind so its probably a pointless battle.

Comment: reject as spam, if the pattern appears to be recurring (read: you find more similar edits), mod-flag.

Comment: As I see no harm, and these are ever unlikely to survive a review, I don't think its worth to spent dev time to prematurely prevent such.

Comment: @Zoe I know there are rejection categories that fit. I am asking what can be or is being done about post like this. Is it just reject and forget or is there something more that is preventing these kind of people from constantly trying stuff like this?

Comment: The problem with banning IPs is that then one troll can get an entire company or apartment building blocked like that. So what would you do if you have 14 different accounts from one IP and then one anonymous user making troll-edits? I suspect no one else in my apartment building has an account at Stack Overflow, and no one trolling with edits, but I'd be a little surprised to get blocked all of a sudden.

Comment: @Scratte Well it would only be an IP ban on edits. Not posting or reading. I would say a short term ban would be fine. Like 24 hours or something similar. An IP ban was just the 1st thing that came to mind. I am also wondering what is currently being done or what could be done.

Comment: You mean until they start posting spam Questions? :) Or would I just get hit with a Question ban on top of the edit ban? What if they post spam Answers? :)

Comment: @Scratte IIRC Anon users can only post _answers_ on SO (and 9(?) other sites), they can't post questions.

Comment: FWIW, I don’t think this is very common. I’m not in the Suggested Edit queue as often these days but you don’t see malicious edits like this very often. I think the fact that their edits never make it into the question makes them give up. Usually it’s a bad but well-meaning anonymous edit or the odd good one. (There’s also someone who often makes good edits anonymously; they use the same phrases for their edit descriptions so I think it’s the same person.)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It’s just two, right? Or can it go up to five if people disagree?

Comment: @BSMP it is not very common at all although they do happen. I've not seen any get even a single approve vote either (and honestly a single approve vote would be enough for a mod flag for that reviewer imo). And yes, first to 2 or a single improve/reject and edit, it doesn't go to 5.

Comment: @BSMP When I was reviewing, every 20 or so reviews was spam.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387506/how-can-an-anonymous-user-get-an-edit-ban-if-all-their-edits-were-approved/387509#387509

Comment: @BSMP I am probably wrong about that, it's so long ago I ever worked at the edit review  queue.

Comment: @BSMP: I hope this guy gave up rather than making more accounts. https://history.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/38874

Comment: @Joshua That appears to be a one-off mistake on their part. If you look at their profile they seem to be doing OK in general (esp. here, they've got 10K rep) and don't appear to have a history of bad edits.

Comment: This is just one of the reasons why anonymous suggested-edits should be disabled altogether.

Comment: @Mast That would depend on how many of the anonymous suggested-edits are actually rejected and how many there are in total? If the percentage is significantly high, we can surely talk about that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't know that we need more tooling than we do at present. Here's what we have already

1. The post owner can control edits by using the Reject button, which undoes the edit (if you have 2k privileges, you can just do a rollback as well)
2. Anonymous user edits must be approved by two reviewers (or by the post owner or moderator)
3. In the event #2 fails (which [does happen from time to time](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16868992)) you should reject the edit and then raise a moderator flag explaining that people made bad edit reviews (be sure to link to the review)

> It is my understanding moderators can see the IP and probably put a block on them for a bit, but there does not appear to be any report option in the suggested edit window.

We can indeed see the IP, but there's not a tool for us to alert the system to stop that IP from doing things. If the user is registered, there's a few more options, and registered users can be banned from suggesting edits, contacted by a moderator, etc. Community Managers might have something, but that path is slow. The vast majority of these seem to be one-off trolls.

In the event someone is actually harassing you with these anonymous edits, please mod flag and link the edits. CMs are more likely to do something if there's an active pattern happening. At the bare minimum moderators can lock posts temporarily to prevent any suggested edits.

Comment: When looking at the respective [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263841/submit-form-when-a-date-is-chosen/39264100#39264100) for the edit that you linked, it looks kind of the post owner (Jaydeep Gondaliya) was banned for the anonymous spam edit. Is this the case?

Comment: What's the purpose of showing the IP then to moderators? Only manual reports to the staff in the case needed?

Comment: "*If the user is registered, there's a few more options, and registered users can be banned from suggesting edits,...*" - So basically we can ban registered users if they behave falsely but can do nothing against anonymous users flooding SO with bad edits? That's crazy.

Comment: @MBT I don't think so.  The review was in 2017, Jaydeep is banned until may 2021, and IIRC normal/automatic bans can only be up to a year long.  (Anything longer requires manual intervention, and I believe can only be done by SO employees.)

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Yes, but the post was deleted 4 months ago:  "It was flagged as spam or offensive content and deleted 4 months ago by Samuel Liew♦." So from that perspective it would fit the time range. I guess there is some other evidence. I was just wondering because the time range fits so well together.

Comment: I don't get this answer, there's no 'reject' or moderator flag in the history of my question's edits? All there is 'rollback'...

Comment: @Hasen I don't see any anonymous edits on your recent posts. The reject option only appears if the edit needed to be approved via review. The alternative is rollback

Comment: @Machavity Ok I didn't realise it was only about anonymous edits. I don't see why we can't report non anonymous edits though? Too many editors and reviewers are far from perfect. I've even had people with non native English correct my native English...you can imagine how that turned out. Or those making redundant edits just for rep by making corrections like "that failed to work" to "that didn't work" adding no value at all.

Comment: You should only report non-anonymous edits when they are destructive, or if someone insists on making an edit you disagree with.

Answer (score 22):

I don't believe so. But that's fine.

Unless you're finding that this happens a significant number of times per unit time, just reject the edit and move on. Don't give them the benefit of your free time trying to follow up on trivial trolling like this. It's not worth it to you, and I'm sure it's not worth it to the moderation team, either.

Comment: But what about robo reviewers who just spam the approve button? These can be dangerous.

Comment: @10Rep FWIW, we have a room we can report them to: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208985/bad-stack-overflow-reviews

Comment: @NathanOliver: Wow that actually exists? What's next, a room to post users we dislike so that everyone else can downvote them?

Comment: @user000001 What's wrong with that room?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore: I'm a bit uneasy with the idea of having rooms where people can post your profile and start mass-flagging you, and maybe even have your user account suspended or destroyed. If you disagree with a review you can engage with the user honestly, rather than mass flagging him without him ever knowing. Does this sound ok for everyone else?

Comment: @user000001 If someone robo reviews, we ban them from reviewing. We don't serial downvote users unless they're spamming random spam/crap. The room for that is charcoal, but even there you don't post a user you dislike and ask everyone to downvote them. That's against site guidelines, and if you see anyone doing that, tell them off/flag them.

Comment: And in that specific room, you just ban them. You don't **_mass flag_** them, and if that was required, mods would step in and send account level messages.

Comment: @user000001 It's really only for clearly incorrect reviews. Like someone doing requires editing instead of unsalvageable or approving spam edits.

Comment: @user000001 One doesn't post users in that room. One posts a review. Some times there's only one reviewer, other times there are more than one. A review suspension is not the same as a site suspension and no one has their account destroyed. If you're uncomfortable with it, feel free to visit the room and see how it works.

Comment: @Scratte: Thanks, from your comment and others' it looks a lot less scary that the initial comment made it look. :)

Comment: @user000001 If someone mass downvotes users as a result of that room, they are misusing it. That said, it's an attempt to catch bad reviews that would otherwise be missed by moderators

Answer (score 6):

If an unwanted edit is proposed, reject it. If an unwanted edit is actually performed, roll it back. (That is the purpose of the <kbd>`rollback`</kbd> button on the earlier state of your post.)

<sub>If they then persist, that's another story. You can then get into a ko fight where each of you keeps rolling back. At that point, call for a moderator. However, in my experience, that sort of thing a rarity on SO.</sub>