# Accidentally made an unneeded edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I just faced a weird issue. I saw a new answer to a question that had code without the formatting, so I sent a suggested edit to the author to include the formatting (e.g., add the triple `` ` ``). Now after submitting, I checked the suggested edit side-by-side, and noticed that the code in the suggested edit in the before section was formatted correctly.

I am not sure what's the cause of this, but I assume the author of the answer edited it while I was sending the suggested edit, but in any case my edit is now "pointless", but I am not sure if it can cause me any issues as it looks like I am making "pointless edits" that do nothing.

I tried to look if there is a way to cancel a suggested edit, but I found there was none. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I retract a suggested edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407857/can-i-retract-a-suggested-edit)

Comment: @JeanneDark No, I don't believe it does.

Comment: You can't cancel or retract a suggested edit.

Comment: Well, I am asking more specifically about the issue with the "ninja edit", and if that can harm me mostly.

Comment: It could be rejected (I guess it already was).

Comment: *"if that can harm me mostly."* If you send *enough* bad edit suggestions, you'll be stopped from sending them (as often) but 1 rejected edit certainly isn't going to do you any "harm".

Comment: I assume you mean https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30056312. Conflicts don't count against you.

Comment: @Zoe I rather guess it was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30191623).

Comment: The reason you cannot retract or cancel a suggested edit is that a rejected edit is the worst that could happen to you and that's deemed not important enough to make devs spend time on it.

Comment: It "only" really hurts your edit statistics. Most reviewers don't see the statistics until after they've reviewed the edit, but some user scripts will include them in the edit review itself.

Comment: @JeanneDark It is indeed that one

Comment: Also, just out of pure curiosity as I know meta doesn't affect rep; but I still kind of want to know why is this post getting down voted, Am I doing something wrong here that I should avoid in the future?

Comment: Your post is a duplicate of sorts. This could be the reason for the votes. The information you want can be found if you spend an eternity learning how to find posts in meta ;) Don't worry about it.

Comment: @Scratte ahh, I see. Well, I've been around stackoverflow for a while, but only recently started to actively contribute, just trying to not make any mistakes if I can help it. Thanks.

Comment: @Scratte gives the most likely reason for downvotes here, IMO. However, in general, voting on any of the Meta sites is different than on the main sites. On Meta sites, votes much more strongly represent people's agreement or disagreement with the position expressed in the post, rather than just an expression of people's opinion on the quality of the post, although they can also reflect that. As a consequence, downvotes on Meta should not be automatically considered to mean that there are problems with the post. On the other hand, it doesn't hurt to double-check that the post quality is good.

Comment: If it hasn't been said before: you can update your edit as long as it hasn't been completely reviewed. So you can edit the post a second time and fix other issues you find some. When there is nothing else to fix in the post, then just wait for the edit to be rejected. Like the answer said, it isn't too bad when you only have a few rejected edits.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191734/349538

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No worries. These things happen. As long as you don't have too many rejected edits, you'll have nothing to worry about.

From [Do the editing penalty durations increase?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355721/do-the-editing-penalty-durations-increase)

> Edit bans come in 3 forms:
>
> 1. When you have enough edits rejected in a short period of time, you will receive an automatic suggested edit ban that lasts 7 days.  This
>    ban is not shorter or longer.  So if you've been banned for a period
>    more or less than 7 days, you likely did not get an automatic ban, and
>    instead were banned manually by a moderator
> 2. Manual edit bans can be levied by moderators for any infraction that they feel warrants a ban (such as editing spam into posts).
> 3. IP level bans used to rate limit anonymous suggested edits.  More explanation on it is in
>    [How can an anonymous user get an edit ban if all their edits were approved?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387506/how-can-an-anonymous-user-get-an-edit-ban-if-all-their-edits-were-approved/387509#387509)

If moderators find that you have a history of unnecessary edits, they might step in and ban you from suggesting more edits, but this wont be the case for a single rejected edit.

> I am not sure whats the cause of this, but I assume the author of the answer edited it while I was sending the suggested edit

Presumably. If a post is edited by the same user with 5 minutes of it being posted/their latest edit (and no other interaction to the post has taken place), the edit will be part of the last revision. I assume that indeed the OP posted their answer, then realized that their code wasn't formatted and so edited it again within this grace period.

You can't retract or cancel suggested edits.

Not much you can do now. Just wait for it to be rejected by the community ([already the case here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30191623)) and move on.